# Drain vs drainage

Tags: discussion, tags

It looks like the tags [drain](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drain) and [drainage](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drainage) are getting blurred. It seems like [drain](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drain) should refer to indoor plumbing issues and [drainage](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drainage) should refer to outdoor/landscaping issues (or something along those lines), but I don't know enough about them to write good descriptions to draw that line. Anyone want to take a crack at it?

Comment: Also the [dwv] tag: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dwv

Answer (score 6):

**Drain**: A channel or pipe carrying off surplus liquid, esp. rainwater or liquid waste.

**Drainage**: The means of removing surplus water or liquid waste; a system of drains.

A *drain* would refer to a single pipe, channel, or path used to remove liquid. Whereas *drainage*, refers to the entire system made up of one or many drains.

Answer (score 1):

I would understand drainage to refer to the water flow through a landscape, or a field or subsoil, whereas a drain would be the man-made aspects - pipes, sewers, channels etc.